# Getting error "commandtext property has not been initialized" when sql compare of Red Gate

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012-express, redgate, sqlcompare

When I compare the 2 databases with the Red Gate's SQL compare then getting below error. "ExecuteReader: CommandText property has not been initialized"

I am using the SQL server 2012 express and Red Gate's SQL Compare 8

Is there any solution?

Thanks,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

SQL Compare 8 (current is 10.4) does not work with SQL Server 2012

http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?t=15296&highlight=commandtext

Comment: I had this issue with Sql Server 2014 on 10.4, upgrading to 11 solved it.

Comment: I believe 10.2.0.1337 supports SQL 2014. No need to upgrade to 11.

http://www.red-gate.com/updatecontrols/details?etc=1679441173&guid=926f53c6-59f2-46c2-b009-13b533c36673&update=831

Answer (score 0):

I let *SQL Compare* update itself from v8.1.0.360 to v11.

It *does* now support comparing the database schema from my SQL Server 12 database... but strangely, after letting it do the upgrade, it has now left *SQL Compare 8* on my laptop aswell.

So, my shortcuts still point at the original v8 version, but I have "SQL Compare v11" in my Start Menu under "Red Gate".

Is there a reason why the Update didn't get rid of the existing version ?

Btw, it's pretty worrying that *SQL Compare 8* threw this bug when used against SQL Server 2012, and demanded an upgrade to fix it.

I wonder if they are trying to sell a few more annual support packages for their $495 piece of software..?

Comment: Allowing major versions side by side is important in cases where the older version supports versions of SQL Server that may have been deprecated in the newer version.